# Help simplify using quadratic formula

Tags: quadratics

$\dfrac{4\pm\sqrt{28}}{2}=2\pm\sqrt7$

My Question is how did $\dfrac{4\pm\sqrt{28}}{2}$ become simplified as $2\pm\sqrt7$

Can you help me by explaining the steps clearly

:) Many Thanks

Comment: You may want to do some revision about [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root)

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $\sqrt{28}=\sqrt{4\times7}=\sqrt{4}\times\sqrt{7}=2\sqrt{7}$.

Hence $\dfrac{4\pm\sqrt{28}}{2}=\dfrac{4\pm2\sqrt{7}}{2}=\dfrac{2(2\pm\sqrt{7})}{2}=2\pm\sqrt{7}$.

Comment: ok then the 4 on top and the 2 on the denominator aren't they simplified?

Comment: what happens to the 2 and the 4

Comment: @user360471 What do you mean?

Comment: @user360471 Hopefully that edit makes it a bit clearer what happened to the 2 and the 4.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{4\pm\sqrt{28}}{2}=$

$\dfrac{4\pm\sqrt{4\cdot7}}{2}=$

$\dfrac{4\pm\sqrt{4}\cdot\sqrt{7}}{2}=$

$\dfrac{4\pm2\cdot\sqrt{7}}{2}=$

$\dfrac{2\pm1\cdot\sqrt{7}}{1}=$

$2\pm\sqrt{7}$

Comment: I admire your patience in explaining elementary stuff in such details. +1

Comment: @PVanchinathan: Haha, not much patience was required in this case :)